# Does Chainlink have an aggregator for its price aggregators?

Tags: erc-20, chainlink

I need a way to pass an arbitrary ERC-20 token symbol and get a price for it in return. The Solidity interface should look something like this:

```
function getPrice(string memory symbol) external view returns (uint256);
```

I browsed through the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/getting-started) but I didn't find something that answers my question. I only saw bespoke instances of asset price aggregators, like this [contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331) that provides ETH/USD data on Kovan.

Does Chainlink provide an aggregator contract for `AggregatorV3Interface` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for an on-chain mapping of Symbol -> USD price.

I'm not sure it makes sense to aggregate aggregators if you're looking for an interface as described.

You have two options to get a mapping of Symbol -> USD Price.

1. Create the mapping yourself
   This is what [Aave currently does](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/dbd77ad9312f607b420da746c2cb7385d734b015/markets/aave/commons.ts#L193)

It would be nice if there was a library for all this... which leads us to #2

2. [Use ENS](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ens)

This way you can just append the Symbol of the string you want to `-usd.data.eth`

ie, if you want ETH / USD:

`eth-usd.data.eth`